# How To Explore New Org?

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, class

I am trying to find out how a `Custom App` is setup and coded in my new company's environment.  Before I was hired they had used a consultant business to do some work.

They had a custom object created called `Territory`.  This object has records of each `User` and what areas they cover.

The thing is I can't figure out what automates the `Contact` record `Owner` assignment.  It references the records from the `Territory` object.

Every morning when new `Contact` records are imported into Salesforce, their' Owners are assigned based upon this `Territory` object.

I looked under Triggers and classes but didn't see anything.  What am I missing, and where/what else could be controlling this?

Comment: How familiar are you with `Apex`? What exactly did you search? Did you search all triggers on `Contact` and referenced classes for `OwnerId`, specifically?

Comment: I did search Triggers for the Contact object, there is only one that is used for Creating 1to1 Acccounts to Contacts. 

Also, how would I look for a referenced class for OwnerID?  I looked for classes by looking at those that werent managed packages, since this was custom and not a managed package.  I didnt see anything that matched as there were only one or two and did other things.

Comment: Ok, so the rabbit hole seems to lead you to look at the `Account` triggers... I don't this sort of functionality could be automated without `Apex`. Maybe if you look at `Process Builder` you might find something `Invocable`. **Are you using an IDE?** If you can just scan your codebase for references to `OwnerId` *everywhere* you should find it.

Comment: Adrian is right, you need to use an IDE like Eclipse to search through all the code. If you feel that that is too much hassle for this one task, you can use aside.io, which is a cloud ide and will allow you to search through all triggers and classes

Comment: First check if you have any third party toll which is doing the assignment tasks externally and updating records in Salesforce.

Comment: You can use the Developer Console to "Find in Files" these days (with limited success....!!) - other automation tools include of course Flow and Workflow. Other third party apps like Distribution Engine can be used to assign things to people as well, so check the "Installed Packages" list for other applications working away in your org?

Comment: @AdrianLarson I did check the Account object previously also, there were no triggers.  There was nothing under the Process Builder either.

Comment: @brezotom I will try a search with Eclipse to search since I've set that up in the past.

Comment: @Ashwani - I was thinking it is an outside job as well but I am being told its done inside Salesforce.  I'm having a hard time convincing the IT department for me to have access to these third party programs, as we use Relational Junction to import the data.

Comment: Okay, Search for the user on which behalf this assignment happens. Setup the debug log for that user and wait. If you can execute the assignment flow with a certain action then set up the debug log for yourself and see whats going on!

Comment: Could it be possible that the data import is setting the values prior to loading by querying the custom objects and assigning the appropriate values to the fields in the file being imported for the contact/account

Answer (score 2):

I'd try exploring this particular use case using the Debug logs from the Developer Console.

Once you have the developer console open go to Debug > Change Log Levels. Make sure the Expiration for the General Trace Settings is in the future (Green). If needed, increase the DebugLevel for the current selection towards the Finest settings. You could do that progressively starting from DEBUG level.

Then either wait until a Contact is inserted or manually insert one using Anonymous Apex. The log will capture everything that occurs (as above, you may need to progressively increase the log level).

There could be a Workflow or Flow hiding in there somewhere that is causing the change. Or an outbound message the occurs when the records are inserted. The log should point you in the right direction.

Comment: I went in and set that up, I notice the expiration is Green but set for 5:13 AM.  However if I try to set for 9AM it turns red.  How can I make it for the morning of tomorrow?

Comment: Nevermind I see I can create Start/End Dates under "New Trace Flag" in settings.

Comment: @Blorg Make sure you are capturing the log for the correct user. I.e. The one who will be creating the Contact records.